# Texture painted in Cycles Render, but the painted texture doesn't show up in Blender Game

Tags: texture-painting

This is probably a silly question, but how can I see those painted bones and muscles to show in Blender Game as part of the mesh?

I painted in Cycles Render. Answer is probably something obvious that I am missing.

Thank you very much, by the way, great community here!

[cycles render](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QDvhu.jpg)
[blender game](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bs0et.jpg)

- Bob

Answer (score 1):

You will need to set up game materials - the game engine doesn't use Cycles as a renderer, and that is why you paint or bake to image and then use those UV mapped textures to create the game assets.